# ajax send data to php not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to send some data to server from javascript using ajax to a server, the js code below.

```
   var username = document.getElementById("username_id").value;

   var array = ["p","c"];    
   var jsonString = JSON.stringify(selectedLocation);
    if(!jsonString) jsonString = "";
    var url = "http://anotherserver/createNewUser.php";
    url = 'proxy.php?url='+url;
    $.ajax({ url: url,type: "POST",data: {username:username,datas:jsonString}, dataType: "json",
    success: function (jsonStr) { 
         var username = jsonStr.Username;
    },

     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

     }

     });
```

and in php,I am getting this variable like,

```
<?php
$username=$_GET["username"];
$datas = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['datas']));
$u= array('Username'=>$username);
echo json_encode($u);
return;
?>
```

I am getting the response successfully but the  `username` is always null.

What can be the problem.

**Edit:**

proxy.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$url=$_GET['url'];
//echo $url;
if (is_string($url)) {
    $url = urldecode($url);
}
$json=file_get_contents($url);
echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: try using `$username=$_POST["username"];`

Comment: Assuming that PHP snippet is from `createNewUser.php`, what **exactly** does `proxy.php` do?

Comment: are u sure u'r url is correctly? `proxy.php/?url=createNewUser.php` ? never seen a construct like that

Comment: @mtizziani looks like it would be `proxy.php?url=createNewUser.php`. Not sure where you got the forward-slash from

Comment: @Phil proxy.php I am using to send the request to outside server.

Comment: No you aren't. `file_get_contents('createNewUser.php')` will read that file from the filesystem, ie the PHP source. I don't understand why you're using `urldecode()` either. PHP automatically decodes request data into the `$_GET` and `$_POST` super globals

Comment: Wait... which of those two PHP blocks are actually used? How are they connected? Are both in `proxy.php` or is one `createNreUser.php`?

Comment: Actyllu the php url is not in in current server but another server. `createNewUser.php` is actually  `http://anotherserver/createNewUser.php`, I have edited the question

Comment: 1) You need to properly encode that `url` query parameter in your JavaScript (see `encodeURIComponent()`). 2) `file_get_contents()` will load a remote URL via GET by default. This can be altered via the `$context` argument. Refer to the PHP manual. 3) Any data you POST to `proxy.php` will not automatically be passed on to the remote URL. You'll need to manually add content to the HTTP context. Again, refer to the PHP manual

Comment: Yes I understand the problem, I passing the arguments to proxy.php instead of createNewUser.php.

Comment: @Phil If you add the above command as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: It's not an answer though. It's a prompt for you to go and do more research.

Comment: Yes the actual solution to the problem was `Any data you POST to proxy.php will not automatically be passed on to the remote URL. You'll need to manually add content to the HTTP context. `

Answer (score 6):

you sending ajax via post method `type: "POST"` and getting data on server via `$_GET`
change it to `$_POST`

Comment: I have change the code to `$username=$_POST["username"];   $u= array('Username'=>$username); echo json_encode($u);` but still the result is null.

Comment: Unfortunately, OP is not POST-ing any data to `createNewUser.php`. Nor are they providing any query parameters

Answer (score 2):

You're using POST method to send data to server while you are using $_GET method on the server side script.

```
<?php
/*$username=$_GET["username"];*/
$username=$_POST["username"];

$datas = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['datas']));
$u= array('Username'=>$username);
echo json_encode($u);
/* $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data); */
return;
?>
```

Comment: What's up with the `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`?

Comment: It's just to read json data from the server. Because the json is sent as raw data not as traditional key=>value pair. and the second argument here is to convert the json_decode to an associative array.

Comment: Not really. It's simply a string posted in `$_POST['datas']`. So it should be `$data = json_decode($_POST['datas'], true);`. However, there should also be some check, since it seems like it could contain an empty string sometimes.

Comment: I edited my answer. Thanks making me realize that I made a mistake.

Comment: No worries. However, you should be able to remove `stripslashes()`. That's shouldn't be needed.